# Message board database design

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm building a message board but I have a question about the database design.
once a new message added, if it is a new message, a subject will be created. The question is, should I keep the create date and the creator of the subject in the subject table, or should I get it from the message table with sql?

**option a - database:**

- user: id, username
- subject: id, subject, create_date, creator_id(user)
- message: id, subject_id, create_date, creator_id(user)

**option b - database:**

- user: id, username
- subject: id, subject
- message: id, subject_id, create_date, creator_id(user)

Second seems better in design, no more repeated data.
But in first option, there will be lighter sql queries..

Which one is better?

Comment: Does the subject has create date and creator different from the message create date and creator or they are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Since the message create date and creator are the same as the subject create date and creator, instead of both options, you can [***normalize***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your tables and store them in one place :

- user: id, username
- subject: id, subject, create_date, creator_id(user)
- message: id, subject_id, Sender_id, Send_date, ReplyMessage_Id.

Comment: but there will be replies to messages. So, there will be multiple messages from multiple users in one subject.

Comment: @potan You can add a nullable foreign key to the same table, as `ReplyMessageId` works as a self join for the reply message.

Comment: message needs date and sender too.

Comment: @potan - OK, sorry, you can add `send_date` sender_id`

Comment: So, option a it is.
I'll put all messages in the subject at first. Reply to any message will be useful later. Thanks.